# CNAME file not copied in gh-pages branch after npm run deploy

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, custom-domain

I have a react app deployed with git hub pages, using `gh-pages` plugin. My `package.json` entry look like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build”,
     .....
   }
```

Eveything worked fine until I tried to use a custom domain.

1. I configured the required A and CNAME entry in my domain provider DNS settings.
2. I created the `CNAME` file in the `develop` branch. That is the branch that I have checked out on my local machine.
3. I run `npm run deploy` on develop branch on local machine.
4. plugin pushed the build code to `gh-pages` branch on remote.
5. the `gh-pages` branch on remote does not contain the `CNAME` file.
6. after every `deploy` I have to manually add the custom-domain from github settings pages section, which eventually create a `CNAME` file. And then every works.

Is there a configuration requied in `package.json` to force `gh-pages` plugin to copy the CNAME file ?

Comment: `gh-pages` won't do that, it's up to _you_ to get `build/` in a deployable state. Maybe add a `postbuild` script that copies the file across (or use `echo` in the `deploy` script as shown [_in the docs_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe updating the deployment line did he trick.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages?tab=readme-ov-file#deploying-to-github-pages-with-custom-domain), you're just missing the `--cname` argument:

```
gh-pages -d build --cname custom-domain.com
```